# cmake generator expressions behave differently in IDE and from command line

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use different target property based on build configuration.
There is imported target called libmongocxx and it has 3 properties for different configs:

- `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG`
- `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`
- `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO`

So, to copy necessary dependencies to build directory I tried to use the following code:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:libmongocxx,$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO>>"
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

The problem is: this works great when I run configuration from IDE (I tried CLion and VS2017), but the same `CMakeLists.txt` fails to configure when I run cmake from command line.
The error `cmake` shows:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:93 (add_custom_command):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:libmongocxx,$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO>>

  $<TARGET_PROPERTY:...> expression requires a non-empty property name.
```

By the way, I already found out that the same task can be more easily solved by using `TARGET_FILE` generator expression, but still, why different behavior in IDE and from command line? 
I discovered this on CMake version 3.12.3, but later tested on 3.14.4 (cmd line only) and it still fails.

**Update**

Here is minimal example to reproduce the issue.
No dependencides required. test.cpp is empty file.
Configuration completes successfully from VS2017 but fails from cmd line.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} test.cpp)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "libd.dll"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "lib.dll"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "libi.dll"
)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${PROJECT_NAME},$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO>>"
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>
)
```

Command line:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
```

**Update2**

Can't agree this question is a duplicate.
The other question is about correct configuration of Visual Studio build.
This question is about usage of cmake generator expressions and about using cmake from command line.

Comment: Both `CMakeLists.txt` and `Findlibmongocxx.cmake` scripts can diffirentiate command line CMake and IDE. E.g., by checking a generator. You show us none of these scripts, so we could only guess why there results are different in different use-cases. Please, prepare [mcve] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Which generator causes the problem?  Or are you saying that Visual Studio generator fails when using CMake at the command line but not when using Visual Studio CMake plugin?

Comment: Well, when command line has been posted, it explains the problem. See duplicate question about correct setting build type for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't agree that this is a duplicate.  This is NOT about changing the build type.  It's about generator expressions and having to account for all build types in `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`.  You'll notice the same error occurs even if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is NOT on the command line.  It's use is just a distraction of the actual problem.

Comment: "This question is about usage of cmake generator expressions and about using cmake from command line." - The duplicate is about the way you attempt to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for Visual Studio in the command line. But I agree with a @Fred that without that attempt your question would definitely be different. Please, remove that attempt from the post (or just remove `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` part, as it has no effect), and I will be happy to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio IDE CMake plugin only uses RelWithDebInfo and Debug configurations (at least for me).  When invoking by the command line the default is all four standard configurations: `Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo`.

Your CMakeLists.txt is incomplete because `MinSizeRel` is not defined or being used so there is no information for the `MinSizeRel` configuration.

BTW, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is ignored for multi-configuration generators. `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` defines which build types should be considered during generation.

So either add in the missing values or change `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`.